# order of functions in Variadic templates

Tags: c++

The following code is working! But my question is theoretical if we inverse the two version of `index_of` in the namespace detail, the compiler says that no function template is matching but why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <typename... Args>
class Pack{
public:
  Pack(){}
};

template <typename T, typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool contains(Pack<Arg, Args...> p)
{
  Pack<Args...> n;
  return std::is_same_v<T,Arg> || contains<T>(n);
}

template <typename T>
bool contains(Pack<> p){
  return false;
}

namespace detail{


  template <typename T>
  int index_of(Pack<> p, int index){
    return -1;
  }

  template <typename T, typename Arg, typename... Args>
  int index_of(Pack<Arg, Args...> p, int index = 0){
    if(is_same_v<T,Arg>) return index;
    Pack<Args...> rest;
    return index_of<T>(rest, index+1);
  }

}

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
int index_of(Pack<Ts...> p)
{
  return detail::index_of<T>(p);
}

int main()
{
  Pack<int,string,double> p;
  cout << contains<int>(p) << endl;
  cout << contains<char>(p) << endl;
  cout << index_of<int>(p) << endl;
}
```

Comment: `if we inverse the two` - then please post the reversed order of functions and ask why the compiler says no function template is matching. Also include used compiler, compiler version and  compiler options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `index_of` itself calls `index_of`. If it's listed first, then the other `index_of` is not visible, so it can only be a recursive call; but the recursive call is not viable once only one type remains.

When it's listed second, both versions of `index_of` are in scope for that call.

Basically, it boils down to the fact that a function has to be declared before it can be called.